# Activiti designer without eclipse

Tags: activiti, bpmn

I am new to Activiti.  I am looking to get a work flow setup for and came across the Activiti designer.  However from looking at this it seems you need eclipse to get started with it?

Can you run activiti designer without eclipse?  Wondering if there was a stand alone tool?  or if you could run it inside a web browser?

Comment: Set up and run activiti explorer war, there is web version of designer, sort of. There is also IDEA outdated plugin. Still eclipse version was better 1 year ago.

Comment: what do you mean by Set up and run activiti explorer war

Comment: https://community.alfresco.com/thread/234565-how-do-i-install-activiti-explorer

Comment: looks straight forward enough however the link for activiti-explorer is 4 years old?  and it doesnt link to the activiti official github?
https://github.com/pcharoen/activiti-web/tree/master/wars

Comment: AFAIK, that's not official github. If you don't care about sources, download war from maven central. For sources (I was using activiti explorer modified by colleagues in previous project), visit activiti.org for direct download of zipped activiti and wars, sources etc. Site has changed a bit though, so it might work a bit different now, and tbh I'm too lazy to reregister just to see links.

Comment: Try these steps in official documentation https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_getting_started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download latest activiti-6.0.0 package from https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/releases/download/activiti-6.0.0/activiti-6.0.0.zip.

The package contains three deployable wars

**activiti-admin.war** => administration web-application  for activiti bpm application to manage deployments,processes,tasks,etc...

**activiti-app.war** => activiti designer to create and export bpm flows

**activiti-rest.war** => activiti server application which is the runtime environment for bpm application and also provides rest APIs for manage flows.

if you are looking for just flow designer then,deploying activiti-app.war into any of application server(like tomcat) can give you the designer flow application which can be accessed in web browser,by default it runs on its own in-memory database so doesn't require external database.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Activiti explorer has a nice Alfresco BPMN Editor built-in.

You can download actiti from the 
To use this Designer you can deploy the activiti-explorer war in a tomcat/or any server.
and open hostname:port/activiti-explorer/ with credentials kermit/kermit

Its a simple yet powerful browser based BPMN modeler.